# no me guarda la información en el sharedPreference

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

al presionar el botón ingresar , me manda los datos a la siguiente actividad pero al cerrar la app no se mantiene los datos, se borran y me vuelve  a cargar la actividad de ingresar datos
Por favor una ayuda , se los agradecería mucho , quiero solucionar este error

esta es el MainActivity

```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    var isRemenber=false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var txtcorreo=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.txtCorreo)
        var txtcontraseña=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.txtContraseña)
        var btnlogin=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnLogin)
        var chkrecordar=findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.chkRecordar)

        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        isRemenber=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CHECKBOX",false)

        if (isRemenber){
           val intent=Intent(this,SegundaActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val correo:String=txtcorreo.text.toString()
            val contraseña:String=txtcontraseña.text.toString()
            val cheked:Boolean=chkrecordar.isChecked

            val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor=sharedPreferences.edit()
            editor.putString("CORREO",correo)
            editor.putString("CONTRASEÑA",contraseña)
            editor.putBoolean("CHEKED",cheked)
            editor.apply()

            val intent=Intent(this,SegundaActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        })
    }
}
```

esta es la segunda actividad

```
    class SegundaActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var preferences:SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda)

        var btnsalir=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSalir)

        preferences=getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        val correo = preferences.getString("CORREO","")
        val contraseña = preferences.getString("CONTRASEÑA","")
        tvCorreo.text=correo+" "+contraseña

        btnsalir.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor=preferences.edit()
            editor.clear()
            editor.apply()

            val intent=Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando ejecutas btnsalir deseas eliminar el valor en la preferencia? si realizas esto entonces se elimina el valor

Comment: exacto , cuando presiono el botón salir elimina el valor para que pueda iniciar sesión otro usuario. Lo que quiero es que se mantenga el valor cuando se minimiza la app  o se cierra desde la multitarea

Comment: Agregue una respuesta,revisa

Comment: Ya entendí lo que decías @carlos, es un error simple. Agregué una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

En la segunda actividad, cuando haces `editor.clear()` lo que estás haciendo es eliminar el contenido de tus `SharedPreferences`

Te dejo el enlace a la documentación para que puedas leerlo. [documentación Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor)

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: el editor.clear() se aplica cuando presiono el boton salir. Lo que quiero es cuando inicio sesión , se mantenga iniciada cuando la minimizo y la cierro desde la multitarea , sin presionar el botón salir. en que estoy fallando amigo??

Comment: Lo que te dice Ariel es correcto, no me había fijado en el nombre que le das a la `SharedPreference` y estás usando dos nombres diferentes. Debes utilizar el mismo para escribir y leer

Answer (score 1):

El problema está a la hora de obtener y escribir los valores en el `SharedPreference`.
Para recuperar el valor utilizas

```
isRemenber=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CHECKBOX",false)
```

En cambio para escribir el valor utilizas

```
editor.putBoolean("CHEKED",cheked)
```

Hay una diferencia en la `key` que utilizas para recuperar y escribir dicha preferencia. Sólo debes cambiarlo y utilizar una sola `key` ya sea `CHECKBOX` O `CHECK`: una de las dos, pero no las dos.

Answer (score 0):

Unicamente debes salir de la Activity pero no realices cambios en la Preferencia:

```
 btnsalir.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            //val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor=preferences.edit()
            //editor.clear()
            //editor.apply()

            val intent=Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        })
```

---

Recuerda tambien que las llaves para guardar y recuperar los valores deben ser las mismas, aqui tienes una diferencia:

Lo obtienes con `"CHECKBOX"`

```
  isRemenber=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CHECKBOX",false)
```

pero lo guardas con `"CHEKED"`

```
  editor.putBoolean("CHEKED",cheked)
```

asegura usar el mismo nombre de llave